# Used pip for pyinstaller but pyinstaller still not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Although I have used pip to get pyinstaller without any errors, command prompt tells me "'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." I also do not see any files named "pyinstaller" in my Scripts folder.

PATH seems to point to the right place. I can pip other packages successfully.

Comment: Is this your issue? [If the pip setup fails to build a bootloader, or if you do not use pip to install, you must compile a bootloader manually. The process is described under Building the Bootloader.](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requirements.html) Also, are you using a virtual environment for your development?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the script. I located it by looking in the paths mentioned when I used pip. Then I had to place it in my already working PATH (which is just my Scripts folder in Python), and rename it to just "pyinstaller"